# Using the Google Maps JavaScript API, is it possible to get data from an outside button into the map.data.setStyle function?

Tags: javascript, html, function, api, button

So I have a large geojson file with about 3,000 polygons and about 10 properties each. I want to have a few buttons on the webpage that pass information into the setStyle function where I can use it to switch between which property is being used to style the map.

Here is the script block along with the two buttons.

```
    <input id = 'Default' type ='button' value ='Default'>
    <input id = 'Ranked' type ='button' value ='Ranked'>

    <script>
      let my_data = JSON.parse('{{ json_data | tojson | safe }}');

      function initMap() {
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('Map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: { lat: 41, lng: -78 },
        });

        map.data.addGeoJson(my_data);

        map.data.setStyle(
          function(feature){
            let income = feature.getProperty('Ranked_Income');
            let houses = feature.getProperty('Ranked_Houses');

            let income2 = feature.getProperty('Normalized_Income');
            let houses2 = feature.getProperty('Normalized_Houses');

            let r, g, b = 0;

            r = '00';
            g = Math.round((income) * 255);
            b = Math.round((1 - income) * 255);

            let color = '#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
            
            return {
              fillOpacity: 0.75,
              fillColor: color,
              strokeWeight: 0.3,
            };
          }
        );
      }
    </script>
```

I want a button to switch between the ranked income and the normalized income. Later on I also want to be able to select various colors, but I can't figure out how to get any outside information into that function.

Answer (score 0):

So I just found a workaround. I just copied the entire map.setStyle block and controlled it with an if statement. I then reloaded the page by calling init map again.

This is likely an awful solution, if anyone has anything better please let me know.